# Google Search Console Intermittently Not Rendering title and description - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo

Google is crawling my pages without error, but it is failing - at least - to render title and description meta content. Out of ~1300 pages, it says I have ~300 duplicate meta content. When I look, the duplicates are like {{metaContent}}.

When I check my pages with site:URL, on some pages, I see a good title and description. On other pages, I see curly braces. Google's documentation suggests that it is pretty good at handling JavaScript, and I figured that AngularJS should be in its wheelhouse.

I'm using Angular v1.5.5 and ngRoute for routing. I've moved the time-consuming API calls to the route resolve like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/route', { 
  templateUrl: 'sometemplate', 
  controller: 'someController', 
  resolve: {stuffINeed: function () {return service.getStuff()}}
})
```

My html in the root scope looks like this:

`<title ng-bind-template="{{title}}"></title>
<meta name="description" content="{{metaDescription}}" />`

Then in my controllers, I am doing:

`$rootScope.title = 'something'
$rootScope.metaDescription = 'something'`

My next attempt to improve things is to not pass $rootScope into the controllers at all and instead to listen to "$routeChangeSuccess" in app.run like this: 
`$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, next, current)`
and then set title and metaDescription on the root scope.

### Update:

I've updated on route change success with some improvement, but I still have duplicate meta content. To be exact, I have 400 duplicates out of ~50k indexed pages. Now it's just the boilerplate below. When I navigate to the page and inspect, I see what I expect. Maybe Angular is not the right tool for this job -- where we want to make Google SEO happy. My hunch is that if my page doesn't render inside of some time threshold, Google won't get the updated title and meta content.

`app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.title = boilerplate
    $rootScope.metaDescription = boilerplate
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, next, current) {
      $rootScope.title = realtitle
      $rootScope.metaDescription = realdescription
    })
   })`

Thanks for reading!

Comment: did you figure this out? i am having the same issue

Comment: Kind of, not really. Just updated.